# I get “Invalid Webhook Token” error while following up an interaction

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have command handler code that’s run function from command files. I tried to ran commands today but I get this in every command after 10-15 mins

I’m using interaction.followUp from command files and have a global command deferring system (with .deferReply({ empheral: true }))

I have no idea why the error is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I waited a few more hours and it fixed itself, interesting…

Answer (score 1):

This was likely due to errors on Discord's side. I ended up debugging this issue for 2-3 hours until it also fixed itself. Incase anyone ends up here again, check https://discordstatus.com/ before debugging any further.

Comment: Nope, this is wayyy more long ago

Comment: I'm aware but the likely cause was that the Discord API had issues then as well. This was the case when I ran into the same issue yesterday. It didn't fix itself, for the same reason it didn't break itself.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32313799)